# Why am I getting a NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler with this NSMutableArray code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong here that would caused this stack trace:

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a8a897a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32b7fd80 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32adbcee -[NSArray containsObject:] + 134
```

Here is the code:

```
NSMutableArray *leftoverArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:itemsArray];
for (NSDictionary *tempItem in tempItemsArray)
{
      if (![itemsArray containsObject:tempItem])
      {
           [itemsArray addObject:tempItem];
      }
      else
      {
           [leftoverArray removeObject:tempItem];
      }
}
for (NSDictionary *item in leftoverArray)
{
      [itemsArray removeObject:item];
}
[mainController.tblView reloadData];
```

`tempItemsArray` is passed in to this class via:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tempItemsArray;
```

I do have this code elsewhere in my app:

```
if (appDelegate.loading)
    appDelegate.tempItemsArray = itemsArray;
else
    appDelegate.itemsArray = itemsArray;
[tblView reloadData];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add an [exception breakpoint](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions) and see what line of code is throwing the exception

Comment: How did you create `tempItemsArray`? Does it indeed contain `NSDictionary` objects?

Comment: This is a crash report from Xcode and I can't repro it on my machine for some reason.

Comment: Modified my code above to add clarity where tempItemsArray is coming from.

Comment: @EthanAllen Are you sure that `tempItemsArray` cannot be made an alias for the `itemsArray`, perhaps by mistake?

Comment: That exception means that you're trying to modify a collection while enumerating it. Is there a part of the code missing? I.e. is tempItemsArray an alias for leftOverArray or itemsArray?

Comment: Added a bit more info. See above. Should I be making a copy instead of a direct tempItemsArray=itemsArray?

Comment: Yes, you should. Currently it is just a reference. You are technically looping and modifying the same array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently tempItemsArray and itemsArray are a reference to the same array object. You are technically looping and modifying the same array at the same time.

Try to make a copy of the array for the tempItemsArray or itemsArray:

```
if (appDelegate.loading)
    appDelegate.tempItemsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:itemsArray];
else
    appDelegate.itemsArray = itemsArray;
[tblView reloadData];
```

Comment: @EthanAllen it should be mutableCopy since your tempItemsArray is declared as NSMutableArray.